# Span and Div position in one line

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

Currently i have a span and a progress div as below-

[image]

But what I want is -

[image]

Current code is

```
<td>
    <span>570</span> <br />
    <div class="progress slim">
       <div class="bar no-text" data-percentage="54"></div>
    </div> 
</td>
```

Removing `</br>` is not working.

> UPDATE: Adding `style="display:inline-block;"` to the progress div makes the div disappeared.

How can I place two contents in one line?

Comment: You need to provide your CSS code so we can see what is potentially overwriting.

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<br />`

If you have additional styling, you can also use the **display: inline** css class.

See here:
http://jsfiddle.net/cz7rh719/

Answer (score 1):

**Remove **

```
<br />
```

**and its inline style should be **

```
style="display:inline-block;"
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `<br />` and add `display:inline-block` for your progress div.

```
div.progress{display:inline-block;}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kkvz0yn9/)

Comment: After adding this style, progress bar is disappeared.

Comment: So other styles are affecting. Can you please replicate it into fiddle?